# Cómo imprimir estos codigos ascii (♥♦♣♠) en c++

Tags: c++

He buscado y encontrado que cada uno de ellos tiene una codificacion por ejemplo el caracter á para realizar su impresion era de la siguiente forma char(0xc3a1); pero obtenía la impresión del caracter í, busqué la codificación del ♥ y obtuve el codigo 0xe299a5, al realizar la prueba tampoco obtuve un buen resultado, continué mi busqueda y encontraba contenido acerca de la codificación UTF-8 pero tampoco entendía mucho cuando se adentraban en el tema, agradecería si alguien me explicara como realizar la impresión de estos carácteres debido a que necesito terminar un proyecto.

Comment: qué sistema operativo usas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si utilizas windows, primero debes establecer el código de página ANSI.

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

Si utilizas *cout* deberás cambiar el modo de búfer debido a que si la cadena comienza con caracteres fuera del rango de *ASCII* no se imprimirá aún forzándolo con `std::flush()`. (incluso llamadas subsecuentes a `cout` dejarían de funcionar, aunque fuesen solo caracteres *ASCII*)

```
setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, 0);
```

Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IONBF, 0);
    cout << "♥♦♣♠\n";
}
```

Lo malo es que no es óptimo debido a que no hay búfer. Mi consejo es que utilices `printf` que no presenta ninguna problemática como cout.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

int main (void)
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    printf("♥♦♣♠\n");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: "*Si utilizas cout deberás cambiar el modo de búfer debido a que si la cadena comienza con caracteres fuera del rango de ASCII no se imprimirá*" [eso no es cierto](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7jZaDr5IvYQpdGvu).

Comment: En Unix por defecto se utiliza utf-8 en las tty y ptty así que ninguna configuración previa es necesaria. En Windows es otra historia, es fácil romper las bibliotecas estándar al utilizar `wincon.h` en general, se recomienda utilizar únicamente las funciones provistas por `wincon.h` en lugar de las estándard, algunos hacks permiten utilizar ambas pero con algún incoveniente (en este caso eliminar el búfer)  https://imgur.com/eH9IfGd

Answer (score 0):

Abrís *CMD*. Vas a *Propiedades* y configuras la fuente mapa de bits y el problema se resuelve parcialmente. Digo parcialmente porque puedes ver los corazones y los otros tres palos pero otros caracteres aparecen en blanco en mi caso.