# Clion no muestra tildes ni la "ñ"

Tags: c++

Cuando compilo texto en español siempre se muestran acentos como símbolos extraños, la codificación del archivo es UTF-8 y el editor está configurado también en español.
Código:

```
#include "iostream"
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    printf("niño á é í ó ú");
    return 0;
};
```

Terminal de salida:

```
ni├▒o ├í ├® ├¡ ├│ ├║
```

Por favor, que alguien me diga si es posible cambiarlo, es demasiado molesto.

Cambié la codificación del archivo y el idioma del editor y nada funciona

Comment: Son problemas típicos de Windows. Ya existen preguntas al respecto. Usa `SetConsoleOutputCP` para cambiar la codificación de la consola a Unicode.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/211212/169744 https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/389990/169744 https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/151363/169744

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    printf("ni\xa4o \xa0 \x82 \xa1 \xa2 \xa3");
    return 0;
};
```

Este codigo creo que soluciona tu problema. Pero aqui te paso una foto con los codigos hexadecimales de los casos más comunes donde se emplea la tilde.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué buen momento para recordar [este comentario](/questions/554492#comment979938_554492)...